# Can you screenshot only the focused window using hardware buttons on the Surface 3?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, screenshot, microsoft-surface

With a regular keyboard when you want to print only the focused window,  instead of the entire screen, you use and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> keys.

I just learned from this site two different methods to print screen on my Surface Pro 3, using just the Surface Pro's hardware.

Is there a way to do Print Window with the Surface Pro 3?

Comment: Do you have snipping tool?

Comment: Using only hardware buttons on the SP3? No.